# Elgg social networking engine alternative

Tags: self-hosted, social-networks, forum, blog, ldap

Although [Elgg](https://github.com/Elgg/Elgg) seems to be actively under development, its community is not as active and many of its [plugins](https://elgg.org/plugins) have not been updated for more than a year and do not seem to be maintained.

What other social networking engine do you suggest as an alternative which is more alive? I need it to support the following features:

- Blogging
- Forum
- LDAP
- Internationalization
- Wiki pages
- User profiles
- Wall (Showing recent activities)
- Roll and group management
- Ability to be hosted locally

Answer (score 1):

You might find [Tiki](https://tiki.org/tiki-index.php) interesting. It's a self hosted groupware platform and wiki that supports all of your listed features either built in or via plugins. It's actively maintained and as a very large community.
I also tried it for a project but it was *just too powerful* but maybe it's exactly what you need.